# Reading a file into Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

The documentation of Asymptote [says](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Files.html#Files) that it can read data contained in  csv files.

The [example](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/westnile.asy) from the homepage of asymptote contains an explicit example to do this. The corresponding raw data file is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/master/doc/westnile.csv). However, I have some data-files where the separator between columns are just blank-spaces rather than commas.

Presumably just the line `file in=input(data).line().csv();` from the above linked code sample has to be tweaked to enable this? I can't seem to find the documentation of the `.line()` and `.csv()` functions in the documentation.

Comment: From the asy docs (asymptote.pdf, v.2.49, p.75):
"...there is a white-space delimiter mode for
reading strings, `file word(bool b=true)`, which causes string reads to respect white-space
delimiters, instead of the default end-of-line delimiter:"
`file fin=input("test.txt").line().word();`
`real[] A=fin;`

Comment: What kind of data are you reading? For reading data into a numerical array, I believe it is default to use space as the column separator; `csv()` changes this from space to comma (although it is a bigger effect when you are reading string data).